# Using request body in SELECT statement

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, twilio

I'm looking for a way to use the body of the request.values.get from my Twilio number to use in my SELECT statement in SQLite.

Basically, if the body of an SMS to my Twilio number is "ABC123" I would like to use that TEXT in my select STATEMENT... Rego='ABC123'. Obviously "ABC123" is dynamic and will change all the time based on user input.. Hope this makes sense, I'm very new to both SQLite and Python. Thanks in advance
Heres my code!!

```
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/sms", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def incoming_sms():

    # Get the message body sent to my Twilio number
    body = request.values.get('Body', None)

#Below carries out the DB lookup based on body sent to my Twilio number
import sqlite3 


conn = sqlite3.connect('VinLookup.db')
c = conn.cursor()


def read_from_db():
    c.execute("SELECT Vin FROM Vin_Data WHERE Rego='ABC123'")
    data = c.fetchall()
    print(data)


read_from_db()   
c.close()
conn.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this, perhaps. All of the database stuff is now in the `read_from_db` function, which accepts the `rego` parameter as input.

```
import sqlite3
from flask import Flask, request, redirect
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse


def read_from_db(rego):
    with sqlite3.connect("VinLookup.db") as conn:
        c = conn.cursor()
        c.execute("SELECT Vin FROM Vin_Data WHERE Rego=?", (rego,))
        return c.fetchall()


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/sms", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def incoming_sms():
    body = request.values.get("Body", "")
    result = read_from_db(body)
    print(body, result)
    # Presumably return something here? A response to the SMS?
```

Comment: Great thanks for your help.. So in response to the SMS would I use # body= request.values.POST("Body", "")